# JSON decode sub array

Tags: php, json, decode

I'm trying to foreach loop with PHP trough a bunch of this kind of JSON code (via a url);

```
{
"abc": [{
    "a": "1",
    "b": [{
        "ba": 1,
        "bb": 2
    }],
    "c": 3,
    "d": [{
        "da": 4,
        "db": 5
    },
    {
        "dc": 6,
        "dd": 7
    }],
    "e": 8,
    "f": 9,
}]
```

I'm able to get the key values of "a", "c", "e" and "f".

I use this code to do so;

```
$url = 'http://url.com/json';

$jsondata = file_get_contents($url);

$jso = json_decode($jsondata, TRUE);

$data = $json['abc'];

foreach ($data as $feature)
{
echo $feature['a'];
}
```

When I try `echo $feature['b']` 'Array' is displayed. `$feature['ba']` displays `Undefined index: ba in <b>x:/test.php</b> on line x`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What's the expected result?

Comment: try this: `$feature['b']['ba']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you loop over `$json["abc"][0]` the keys will be a, b, c, d, e and f.

```
$url = 'http://url.com/json';
$jsondata = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($jsondata, TRUE);

$data = $json['abc'][0];
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    var_dump($key, $value);
}
```

`"ba"` would be: `$json["abc"][0]["b"][0]["ba"]`

`"dc"` would be: `$json["abc"][0]["d"][1]["dc"]`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Your insight helped me a great deal!